# File's Owner is not showing Tab bar controller Outlet?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have included Tab Bar Controller in my application.
I have declared Outlet in the App Delegates' .h and .m file.
When I am right clicking on File's Owner, It doesn't show me Outlet.
OR
If I double click on the Tab Bar Controller I could not see the Outlet.
How to connect it...
I have Included the XIB file in an empty app.
I am using Xcode 4.
Any body can tell me how to get APPLICATION DELEGATE icon when clicking on xib file...??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the app delegate icon and not on the file's owner.

[image]

Did you set the class for that xib or not. you can check that in the custom class group like in this pic. If not than you should set it with a class name of your choice.

Comment: I could not find Application Delegate Icon......How to get it?I have seen it in the example but I could not see it shere you have mentioned.....

Comment: can you any item in the list with delegate at the end.

Comment: Parden, Please elaborate..As i Got..I could not see Tab bar Controller outlet anywhere reply pls...

Answer (score 1):

Arpit, Instead of declaring Outlet in ProjectNameAppDelegate.h file that is being shown in side list... declare in .h file with the same name as .xib file... Same problem has been faced my me also... Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the the type "'Object'" and drag it to the Below the File's Owner Window.
Set it's Class to your present appln delegate..this is the way you can create app delegate if not present by default near file's owner.